# Why doesn't Vite build out my components folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I am running a simple react project and using Vite as my builder. But for some reason the config is ignoring building out my components folder into my ./dist folder. I cant seem to find anything online that helps solve this. Does anyone have an idea? I have my config below, my index.ts file and a screenshot of my file directory.

`Github:` https://github.com/jaysnel/CardanoJS

**File Directory:**

[image]

`vite.config.js:`

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: './src/index.ts',
      formats: ['cjs', 'es'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        components: resolve(__dirname, './src/components/index.ts'),
      },
    },
    target: ['esnext'],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@namejs': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
  ],
});
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@namejs/react",
  "version": "0.1.3",
  "author": "Jaysnel",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/react.js",
  "module": "dist/react.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./dist/react.js",
      "require": "./dist/react.cjs"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "plugin:storybook/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.3",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.6",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.13",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "storybook": "^7.4.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2"
  }
}
```

`src/index.ts:`

```
export * from './components';
```

`src/components/index.ts`

```
export * from './CardanoWallet'
```

Comment: what file was ignored?

Comment: @XGG my entire components folder and the index.ts file should also be built into the dist folder. I only get react.js and react.mjs

Comment: @JaySnel Share the code for `src/components/index.ts`

Comment: @RobinThomas Was actually just updating this. Added that and a image of the open components folder as well

Comment: @JaySnel Instead of using the `resolve` field, can you use the `vite-tsconfig-paths` plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths

Comment: @RobinThomas Ahh, unfortunately this was the last thing I tried before making this post, it gives me the same result as resolve. Im curious if the package.json file has anything to do with this

Comment: @JaySnel Possible to share a github repo for this? Will be easier for me to debug.

Comment: @RobinThomas Absolutely.  https://github.com/jaysnel/CardanoJS

Comment: @JaySnel Have written an answer. Do check if that clarifies all your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite actually bundle your `components` directory into your `react.js` and `react.mjs` output files.

The issue here is that since it's exported as default export, it's not easy to understand that from the contents of the above output files.

So to help with that, if you can change your `src/components.ts` file to:

```
export { default as CardanoWallet } from './CardanoWallet/CardanoWallet';
```

and then build the output files, you can find `CardanoWallet` in those files.

---

On an unrelated note, I have cleaned up your `vite.config.ts` to reduce/improve your bundle.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import tsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/index.ts',
      formats: ['cjs', 'es'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tsConfigPaths(),
    react(),
  ],
  define: {
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
  },
});
```

1. I added a `define` so that it doesn't bundle development code.
2. Its good to keep `react` and `react-dom` as externals (meaning, they wont be bundled into your library). Reason being, the client using your library might be using react, in which case, there shall be 2 copies on `react`, which will result in error for your clients.
3. Added `tsConfigPaths`, since no need to add `resolve` yourselves.

Comment: Interesting, i was expecting this to build out an actual folder inside of dist called `components` but this works! Thank you so much! I was def using that plugin wrong